# How to increase the height of a row in jtable depending on the text content entered in its cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable which is editable. As and when the cells are written with the text by user,if the entered text is more to fit the size of cell then the height of the row in table must increase to fit the new text entered by user. Could you tell me how to increase the height of the row depending on the lines of text entered.

Can anyone help me in this?
I have tried to add JTextArea into a row, but this is not working.

Comment: i want the jtable width to be fixed. So when the text entered is more than width then it should appear in next line of the cell.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to calculate the needed height for the newly entered text. Depending on the renderer you are using for the cell, you can use e.g. `JTextArea.getLineCount()` to find out how many lines the text contains.

Then you need to retrieve the height of the font used by the renderer and calculate the needed height out of that.

Once you have that number, use `JTable.setRowHeight(int, int)` to change the height for the specific row.

Something like this:

```
Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(theTable, theTable.getValueAt(row, col), false, false, row, col);
Font f = c.getFont();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(f);

// this cast depends on the way your renderer is implemented !!!!
int lineCount = ((JTextArea)c).getLineCount();

int fheight = fm.getHeight();
int rowHeight = lineCount * fheight;


theTable.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight); //NOTE: rows and columns are zero-indexed
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of a row in a JTable component is based on an assigned value rather than on the preferred height of the renderers used in that row :

[www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/RowHeight.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022002843/http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/RowHeight.html)

Comment: Your link isn't valid now. Please upgrade it or remove it from your question (that in my opinion, is a little sort).