# Multiline feature in an editable jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to have multiline feature for **JTable** cells. Wherein the cell automatically expands and shrinks itself when user writes or deletes text in/from cell. I have set columns width, but it doesnt automatically adjust itself according to user's input, rather text beyond the width are not seen at all, but i have a requirement to fix on the width. Can anyone help me with this, to have **self adjusting and multiline feature for jtable cell**. Would be very thankful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225946/how-to-increase-the-height-of-a-row-in-jtable-depending-on-the-text-content-ente

Answer (score 3):

Several steps:

- implement a custom renderer using a JTextArea as rendering component
- implement a custom editor using a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane as editing component
- add logic (aka: TableModelListener) which updates JTable's individual rowHeight based on the renderer's preferred size on receiving a change notification